# No pairs when drawing cards from deck

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we are dealt five cards from an ordinary 52-card deck. What is the probability that we get no pairs (i.e. all cards are different values).

I'm not sure if I've got the right answer on this one. My logic is that we pick 5 cards out of 13 possibilities. Then every card also has 4 possibilities for a colour. Somehow I feel that this is incorrect.

So my solution would look like:

$P(no pairs) = \frac{\binom{13}{5} \cdot 4}{\binom{52}{5}} $

Am I wrong and if so where? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a naive approach, we start with card 1. It has some pip value (Two, Jack, Ace, whatever).

Now, when we go to draw card 2, there are 48 cards out of the 51 remaining that don't have that pip value.

Now, when we go to draw card 3, there are 44 cards out of the 50 remaining that don't have either of the previous two pip values.

And so on. Can you construct the probability from here?

Comment: Yes! Then it would be 52*48*44*40*36. But how would this be expressed in terms of combinations?

Comment: Well, notice this approach doesn't rely on combinations; it relies on straight-up probability. On your second draw, the probability of drawing a card that has a different pip value than the first is $\frac{48}{51}$. On your third draw, the probability of drawing a card with different pip value is $\frac{44}{50}$. Since both events have to happen, what do we do with these probabilities?

Comment: We use the multiplication principle, hence the probability has to be ($\frac{48}{51} \cdot \frac{44}{48} \cdot \frac{40}{44} \cdot  \frac{36}{40})$?

Comment: We do use the multiplication principle, but be careful with your fractions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! So it would basically be $(\frac{52}  {52} \cdot \frac{48}{51} \cdot \frac{44}{48} \cdot \frac{40}{44} \cdot  \frac{36}{40})$

Comment: Ahhh! I saw my mistake. :-) One second.

Comment: It would be $\frac{52}{52} \cdot \frac{48}{51} \cdot \frac{44}{50} \cdot \frac{40}{49} \cdot \frac{36}{48}$

Comment: And there you go!

Answer (score 2):

The denominator ${52 \choose 5}$ is correct: the number of ways of choosing 5 cards from 52.

If we are going to get no pairs, we can choose any of the 52 for the first card.
But we can only choose 48 for the next card, since 3 of the remaining 51 would give a duplicate.  We can only choose 44 for the card after that, 40 after that, and 36 for the last one.

Hence, the probability is 
$$
\frac{\frac{52*48*44*40*36}{5!}}{52 \choose 5}
$$

Which is 
$$
\frac{4^{5}*{13 \choose 5}}{52 \choose 5}
$$

In other words, you're missing a $4^{4}$ in your computation because each of the 5 cards can be any of the 4 suits.

Comment: In your first display, you have ordered selections upstairs and unordered downstairs.

Comment: Good call.  That removes the 5! from upstairs, leaving 4^5 (13 choose 5)/(52 choose 5), which makes sense in terms of what the asker was saying.  I'll edit it.